# Stack NSViews like Facetime for OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, interface-builder

I've been trying to stack a view on top of another one to mimic Facetime's overlay effect when browsing the contact list.

[This is what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Est0C.jpg)

[image]

So far I've managed to do it by nesting the **Overlaying View** inside the **Slide View** in Interface Builder.

Slide View contains both Image View and Overlaying View

I have two problems with this solution:

1) Every time the **Image View** is replaced with a new image, I have to move it to the back doing this :

```
self.currentImageView!.removeFromSuperview();
self.animator().addSubview(newImageView!, positioned: NSWindowOrderingMode.Below, relativeTo: nil)
```

2) **Slide View** is used for the transition whenever the image in **Image View** is replaced. The **Overlaying View** ends up being included in the transition.

**Question:** Is there a way to achieve this without having to nest the overlaying element inside the element it is covering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a way to do it.

I placed the Overlaying View above the Slide View in interface builder and did the following in the Window Controller's windowDidLoad() function :

slideView.wantsLayer = true
overlayingView.wantsLayer = true

slideView and overlayingView are set as outlets in the controller.

I did try this before but I was setting the overlayingView's layer to be true first and the view would appear under the other one.

Don't hesitate to post a prettier solution, this one might just be a little hack.